# getting 'pma_history' marked as crashed in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i am having problem with mysql , i am getting Table.'\phpmyadmin\pma_history' is marked as crashed and should be repaired .

which is creating problem for my site to access the database

can anybody help me to rid this error .

Answer (score 1):

From the console (or anywhere you can run commands), run "repair table phpmyadmin.pma_history". See the [repair table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html) command. [Check table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/check-table.html) is also helpful.